# Getting IIS application pool recycle events to be logged in the Windows Event Log

Tags: iis, logging, iis-7, event-log, application-pool

I am trying to get **IIS 7** application pool recycle, start, stop, etc. events to be logged to the Windows **Event Log**. I followed the steps outlined in [this article](http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=17) but didn't have any success. I restarted the application pool and nothing was logged in the Event Log. (I checked both the "Application" and "System" logs.) But when I do an IIS reset that gets logged.

Comment: The referenced article discusses IIS 6, not IIS 7 as the question is tagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article made it clear why events were not registered in event log:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/02/28/why-iis6-application-pool-recycle-events-are-not-logged.aspx

Comment: The referenced article discusses IIS 6, not IIS 7 as the question is tagged.

Comment: that article (from 2006, already archived in 2011) no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

For **IIS 7**, IIS Manager can be used to [enable recycle events to be logged](http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx) in the Windows Event Log:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Click **Application Pools**.
3. Click the application pool of interest and click **Advanced Settings...**.
4. Under **Recycling**, expand **Generate Recycle Event Log Entry**.

The available recycle events that can be logged are:

- Application Pool Configuration Changed
- Isapi Reported Unhealthy
- Manual Recycle
- Private Memory Limit Exceeded
- Regular Time Interval
- Request Limit Exceeded
- Specific Time
- Virtual Memory Limit Exceeded