# How can I get more detail about ASP.NET app restarts than HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I'm troubleshooting restarts in an ASP.NET application. The application is restarting about 20 times a day. I'm logging using the log4net library. Following advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829392/how-to-discover-the-reason-of-asp-net-application-restart),   I have the application logging the reason for the shutdown from `HostingEnviornment.ShowdownReason` inside the `Application_End()` event in Global.asax. I also log when the application starts up in the `Application_Start()` event.

After running the logs for several days, I've found that when a shutdown is actually logged, the reason for the restart is always `HostingEnvironment`. But the shutdown is not always logged. I know that because I can see `Application_Start()` log events that don't have a corresponding `Application_End()` event.

What would cause the hosting environment to restart my application? Is there a way to get more specific information about why it decided to trigger the restart? Does the fact that the shutdown event is not always logged shed any light on what may be causing the restarts?

**UPDATE**

I'm still struggling with this. [Links](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/debugging-aspnet_wp-in-production.html) [from](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/05/14/asp-net-performance-issue-large-number-of-application-restarts-due-to-virus-scanning.aspx) [around](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817662(pandp.10).aspx) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829392/how-to-discover-the-reason-of-asp-net-application-restart) [web](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rextang/archive/2007/07/24/4026494.aspx) seem to indicate that using WinDbg/SOS.dll/ADPlus.vbs will be necessary to track down the cause of this issue. But between learning how to use these tools and figuring out how to correctly interpret the results, it seems to come with a very steep learning curve. I'm kind of still hoping there is something out there that can help me track down the cause of the restarts without resorting to disassembling CLR code. Does anyone have any other tools or tricks that can help me with this?

Comment: A sidenote, take a look at your application pool and the memory it consumes. If the process goes out of control, you can almost predict when services will stop and restart. I've seen app pool's that have gone out of control and gradually exhaust all available system physical memory.

Comment: I've been working on logging performance counters along with everything else. Right now I am logging the results of `GC.GetTotalMemory(False)`, but I'm not sure that is really telling me what I want to know -- the restarts don't always appear to be correlated to the highest memory usage of the app. Is there a better  thing, perhaps a performance counter, that I should be looking at?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that I am interpreting my logging correctly. Perhaps you can shed light on that also. See my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428440/application-pools-and-worker-process-threads

Comment: You won't get an Application_End() even if the process is forcefully shut down.  You only get Application_End() if IIS shuts down the process gracefully.